# Query different field than defined in return for a ManyToMany field option

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am new to Django and have a problem that I am trying to fix. In my application I have a model Asset which has multiple choice answer from AFF. Here is the code:

```
class Rtype(models.Model):
    rtype_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Type", default = "")
    rtype_score = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name="Score", default = "")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rtype_name


class AFF(models.Model):
    ff = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="FF", default = "")
    ff_score = models.ForeignKey(Rtype, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Score", default = "")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ff

class Asset(models.Model):
        fjam = models.ManyToManyField(AFF, verbose_name="Fjam", default = "", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fjam
```

Let's say there are following entries in the database:

rtype_name = Critical

rtype_score = 5

rtype_name = Medium

rtype_score = 3

ff = Direct

ff_score = Critical

ff = Indirect

ff_score = Medium

If user chooses in Asset form, both Direct and Indirect, how can I save 3 + 5 in the database when they submit the form instead of rtype_names by keeping return self.rtype_name in Rtype (useful for showing user a name rather then a score).

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to work out what you want here, and failing.

Your Asset model has a m2m relationship with AFF; the thing that will be saved in the database when the user selects Direct and Indirect will be the primary keys of the AFF items that have those ff values. You can get the score by following the foreign key to RType for each item. For example:

```
for aff in my_asset.fjam.all():
    print(aff.ff, aff.ff_score.rtype_score)
```

(You might consider giving your fields more descriptive and relevant names.)